# Centering elements in space remaining after placing another element

Tags: android

In my `android` app, I have a toolbar with an `ImageView` and two spinners. I would like the `ImageView` to appear flush with the left side of the screen, and the two `spinners` to be evenly spaced, horizontally centered in the remaining space (not horizontally centered on the screen, but horizontally centered in the space remaining after the `ImageView` is placed. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id\img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id\img"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The relative layout fixes the relative positions of the image and spinners (as a group).  The Linear layout sets the spinners and centers them within the layout horizontally by setting the layout gravity.

I'm assuming you want them one on top of the other.  If you want them side by side, change the orientation.